# Random variable is the difference between the product of noncentral and central normal variables

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable

What is known about the distribution $X$ that is the difference between the product of noncentral normals and central normals, where all normals are independent? Can someone recommend a paper or interesting relation to other distributions?

$$X\sim x_1 x_2-x_3 x_4$$

with $x_{1,2}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_{1,2},1),\quad x_{3,4}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Note: We can also express $X$ solely by independent standard normal variables $y_i=\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, i.e. $X\sim (y_1 + \mu_1) (y_2 + \mu_2) - y_3 y_4=y_1 y_2 - y_3 y_4 + \mu_1 y_2 + \mu_2 y_1 + \mu_1 \mu_2$.

Comment: Use the technique at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/590759/919 to express this as a difference of two *iid* non-central chi-squared$(2)$ distributions.

Comment: Is this the only possibility?

Comment: In what sense?  The answer is determined by the suppositions, making it unique.