# Distribution of sum of products of 3 (non)central normal variables

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable

What is known about the distribution of the random variable $X$ that is a cubic form of independent central and noncentral normal variables
$$X\sim y_1 y_2 y_3- y_1 x_1 x_2  - y_2 x_3 x_4- y_3 x_5 x_6+x_1 x_4 x_5 + x_2 x_3 x_6$$
with

$y_i\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mu_i,1\right)\\x_i\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)$

Maybe someone knows a paper that deals with such patterns of cubic forms.

Comment: Given the vague similarity to your previous question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/591696/random-variable-is-the-difference-between-the-product-of-noncentral-and-central, could you please explain what you mean by "such patterns"?  Arbitrary polynomial functions of independent Normal random variables, perhaps?

Comment: By pattern I mean cubic forms of normal variables, i.e. sums of products of 3 factors of normals, mixed central and noncentral. I am interested in the special given case but maybe there is a theory about a similar or more general case. Therefore I used "pattern".

Comment: That helps us understand the direction of your question.  Could you explain the statistical setting in which this arises?

Comment: It is related to the signed volume of a tetrahedron where all coordinates are noncentral normal distributed.

Comment: The direction to look, then, would be into the distribution of determinants of random matrices.

Comment: Can you please add new information in comments as an edit to the post! We prefer posts to be self-contained, few people read comments, and comments can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Because your profile says you have access to *Mathematica*, you can easily find moments of $Z$:

```
z = y[1] y[2] y[3] - y[1] x[1] x[2] - y[2] x[3] x[4] - y[3] x[5] x[6] + x[1] x[4] x[5] +
    x[2] x[3] x[6];

dist = TransformedDistribution[z, Flatten[{Table[x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], {i, 6}],
  Table[y[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ[i], 1], {i, 3}]}]];

Mean[dist]
(* μ[1] μ[2] μ[3] *)
Variance[dist]
(* 6+2 μ[1]^2+2 μ[2]^2+μ[1]^2 μ[2]^2+2 μ[3]^2 + μ[1]^2 μ[3]^2 + μ[2]^2 μ[3]^2 *)
Skewness[dist]
```

[image: Skewness]

```
Kurtosis[dist]
```

[image: Kurtosis]